Receiving 'Unable to access JAR files' error when switching workspaces in Eclipse after installing Spring Tools 4
I'm experiencing an issue with Spring Tools 4 in Eclipse where the language server fails to load correctly when switching workspaces. The specific error is:
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\Program Files\eclipse\...\Users\[user_name]\.eclipse|org.eclipse.platform_4.30.0_1709980481_win32_win32_x86_64\plugins\org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls_1.59.0.202411281450|servers\spring-boot-language-server\spring-boot-language-server-1.59.0-SNAPSHOT -execjar
While I can temporarily fix this by uninstalling and reinstalling Spring Tools, the error reappears whenever I switch to a different workspace. The plugin shows as already installed in new workspaces, but doesn't function correctly until reinstalled.
Environment:

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (version 2023-12 (4.30.0))
Spring Tools 4 (version 1.59.0)
Windows 11

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Spring Tools through Eclipse Marketplace, and clearing workspace metadata, but both solutions only work temporarily until I switch workspaces. The plugin shows as installed in each workspace but requires a complete reinstall to function correctly.
Im expecting Spring Tools to work consistently across all workspaces once installed, without needing reinstallation after each workspace switch.

Does this happen with a fresh vanilla installation of the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution from https://spring.io/tools as well?

Looks like you've installed the latest Spring Boot Tools plugin into Eclipse 4.30 which is a bit older than the supported 4.32. I'd switch to the latest 4.34 even. It's odd that JAR file name is spring-boot-language-server-1.59.0-SNAPSHOT -execjar instead of spring-boot-language-server-1.59.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar Is this a typo? Look in the Eclipse workspace log file. Find entry starting with !MESSAGE Command list starting LS: org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls then between START and END there is the multiline command to start LS JAR. Do you mind pasting it here?

@aboyko yup, that's a typo! Here's the log file snippet:
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.9.v20231028-0858\jre\bin\javaw.exe -Dsts.lsp.client=eclipse -Xmx1024m -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.properties -Xlog:jni+resolve=off -XX:ErrorFile=C:/Users/[user_name]/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls/fatal-error-spring-boot_1735450175757 -Dlanguageserver.hover-timeout=225 -jar  C:\Program Files\eclipse\..\..\Users\[user_name]..-1.59.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar

@aboyko The complete file path for the last line C:\Program Files\eclipse\..\..\Users\[user_name]..-1.59.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar actually expands to C:\Program Files\eclipse\...\Users\[user_name]\.eclipse|org.eclipse.platform_4.30.0_1709980481_win32_win32_x86_64\plugins\org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls_1.59.0.202411281450|servers\spring-boot-language-server\spring-boot-language-server-1.59.0-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar

@MartinLippert I haven't tried the fresh installation from spring.io/tools yet. I was a bit confused at first because instead of a self-extracting JAR, I got a ZIP file and had to figure out how to set up Spring Boot projects from it. I've now downloaded Spring Tools 4 from the site because the error has become constant, whereas before it only happened when switching workspaces. So far with the fresh installation, I haven't encountered any issues in my testing.

@AbelMathew Glad to hear that the fresh install works fine. My guess is that the exact location of the spring tools plugins (when you installed them into an existing Eclipse) causes some issues. Not sure what the issue exactly is though. Another thing to note is that the Eclipse version that you installed the Spring Tools into seems to be rather old and not supported by the latest version of the Spring Tools, so in case you need to install the Spring Tools into an existing Eclipse installation again, make sure that you use the latest version of the Eclipse IDE.
